# How do i properly format a Mysqli query result in PHP? And is there an equivalent to mysql_field_table() for mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

So I am writing a small PHP framework for fun, and I have come to a point where I need to format an arbitrary query result into this format:

```
Array(<br>
[tablename]<br>
  [fieldname] => value<br>
  [fieldname] => value<br>
[tablename]<br>
  [fieldname] => value);<br>
<br>
```

If I was doing this in mysql, I would simply do it this way:  `$tmp[mysql_field_table][mysql_field_name] = $value.`  But I chose to do this project using mysqli, and I can't seem to find an equivalent for `mysql_field_table()` so I can determine the table for each individual value.  What is the ideal method for gaining this result?

Comment: u can perform a query, and yet without knowing the tablename? re-think, is a serious logic problem

Comment: I'm building a framework, so the query is arbitrary.  My query() function has to be able to take any random data and put it into a specific format based off of the table each field is in. Figured it out though, so I'm good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the example [here](http://php.net/mysqli-result.current-field) in the manual; the return value of the function documented is an object with a member called 'table'.

This gives you what you need.